# How to identify the topmost parent control?

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am automating a WPF application using Coded UI.

So, while creating a object of a control say WpfText i need to say:

```
WpfText tag = new WpfText(parent);
```

Here i need to pass the parent control to the constructor, So is there a way to find the parent control of a particular control in wpf application?

I can record it using Coded UI test builder and then see the generated code but is that the only way ? bcz i find it too cumbersome to do this way.

Comment: I am not very familiar with coded UI tests so maybe there is something here I am missing, but can you not just call the `Parent` property of the control in question?

Comment: do you have the direct access to the wpf control?

Comment: This is a wpf application installed on my machine. I don't know what is the parent control of this.

Answer (score 1):

Within a Coded UI test the `TopParent` property of the `UITestControl` class, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.topparent(v=vs.100).aspx) for more details, can be used. To move up through the ancestors of a control towards the top parent the `GetParent` method of the same class, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getparent(v=vs.100).aspx), can be used. There are several other methods in the class for other ways navigating through the control hierarchy.